# What does the command `csrutil clear` do?

Tags: macos, sip

When I read the arguments of `csrutil` it says `csrutil clear` will erase the existing configuration SIP:

```
csrutil
usage: csrutil <command>
Modify the System Integrity Protection configuration. All configuration changes apply to the entire machine.
Available commands:

    clear
        Clear the existing configuration.
    disable
        Disable the protection on the machine. Only available in Recovery OS.
    enable
        Enable the protection on the machine. Only available in Recovery OS.
    status
        Display the current configuration.

    netboot
        add <address>
            Insert a new IPv4 address in the list of allowed NetBoot sources.
        list
            Print the list of allowed NetBoot sources.
        remove <address>
            Remove an IPv4 address from the list of allowed NetBoot sources.
```

My question is does executing `csrutil clear` erase the configurations for SIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [System Integrity Protection – Adding another layer to Apple’s security model](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/):

> When `csrutil clear` is run, SIP goes back to its factory-default settings. That means SIP is enabled if it was disabled previously and any custom configuration is cleared out.

The custom configuration consists of a list of IP addresses of allowed NetBoot sources.